# Trying to use DATEDIFF() and CURDATE() functions to receive a result of days in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Database: (gameDay)

```
id            game_Date
1             1996-01-02
```

I am trying to return the amount of days it has been since this game took place.

The sql query I was trying to run was:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - gameDay.game_Date AS days
FROM gameDay
WHERE gameDay.id = 1
```

this was giving me weird number which made no sense:

OR

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), gameDay.game_Date) AS days
FROM gameDay
WHERE gameDay.id = 1
```

This sql query was giving me an error of

> Undefined function or expression: CURDATE

OR

> SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CURDATE(), gameDay.game_Date) AS days
>       FROM gameDay
>       WHERE gameDay.id = 1

and this query gives me this error:

> Field is not a valid field based on tables in the query: DAY

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: mySQL, my apologies

Comment: . . `CURDATE()` is definitely a MySQL function.  Are you sure that is the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
IF you use SQL Server database means try below query :

  SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(), gameDay.game_Date) AS days
  FROM gameDay
  WHERE gameDay.id = 1 

IF you use MySQL database means try below query :

  SELECT DATEDIFF(`game_Date`, NOW()) AS days
  FROM `gameDay`
  WHERE `id` = 1
```

Comment: I meant to post this as well, I get an error with this message if I use that query

> Field is not a valid field based on tables in the query: DAY

Comment: @Draklin,I updated my post.Use second query for MYSQL.

Comment: Thank you, but still running into this error: Undefined function or expression: NOW